# Changing OpenID

Tags: support, openid, user-accounts, login, linked-accounts

I realize this has been answered, but I can't get it to work. I have a new Google account, and I want to associate it with my existing Stack Overflow account. When I log in using "add opened", it just logs me in to a new account with 1 reputation, and it doesn't migrate the new  account to my old (current) profile and information. What am I doing wrong here? It is the same when I try Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Jeff's blog post about this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/we-now-support-multiple-openids/), you need to email team@stackoverflow.com with either the user IDs or the User page URLs to be merged and they will combine them for you.

Comment: Alright, will do that, thanks :)